# SSMS Error: Unable to proceed with DAC operations on the target instance because it does not support DACs

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016, dac

I'm trying to deploy a DAC package to a database (registered as a Data Tier Application) on an instance of SQL Server 2016 SP1 (13.0.4001.0) using SSMS v17.4 but I'm getting the error:

Unable to proceed with DAC operations on the target instance because it does not support DACs.

I think SSMS 17.4 is the latest version.  Why can't this deploy a DAC to an instance of SQL Server 2016?  Is there a setting in SSMS that I've missed?

[image: SSMS Error]

Answer (score 1):

Your must have sysadmin server role to upgrade Data-tier Applicaton

UPD: You can download Data-Tier Application Framework (DacFx) 17.4 https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=56356 and use SqlPackage utility to deploy DAC package. It doesn't require sysadmin, serveradmin server fixed role if you don't create/drop/alter logins.

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /sf:"<path to dac package>" /tcs:"Data Source=<server_name>;Initial Catalog=<database_name>;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```